# Why Google change the Bitmap pixel data storage to native heap in Android 8.0?

Tags: java, android, c++, bitmap

Here is the link to android developers [Managing Bitmap Memory documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory.html).

And the content :

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap. The pixel data in native memory is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash. From Android 3.0 (API level 11) through Android 7.1 (API level 25), the pixel data is stored on the Dalvik heap along with the associated bitmap. In Android 8.0 (API level 26), and higher, the bitmap pixel data is stored in the native heap.

Comment: Isn't it pretty clear? Enhanced **memory management**.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès It presents a whole new set of issues, as I've written here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091403/878126